# How to read this GPU usage in running TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have two anaconda environments for TensorFlow_CPU and TensorFlow_GPU. I want to test the speed difference between the CPU and GPU version. So at two terminals I am running the same program:

```
python grid.py
```

This is training a MLP neural network. I want to see how faster the GPU running than the CPU running. While they are both running, I printed the following:

```
[martin@A08-R32-I196-3-FZ2LTP2 ~]$ nvidia-smi
Wed Jan 23 04:52:56 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0    49W / 250W |  21817MiB / 22919MiB |     14%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   33C    P0    49W / 250W |    231MiB / 22919MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:83:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   27C    P0    48W / 250W |    231MiB / 22919MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   35C    P0    51W / 250W |    231MiB / 22919MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0    186812      C   python                                     21807MiB |
|    1    186812      C   python                                       221MiB |
|    2    186812      C   python                                       221MiB |
|    3    186812      C   python                                       221MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this indicate that 4 GPU are all being used, but the '0' is used heavily but others are slightly used? Compared with the small 2G ram GPU on my Ubuntu desktop, this powerful 4-GPU machine doesn't seem to speed up on this training task.

EDIT: The full code is below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

import time

import numpy as np

start_time = time.time()

# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model(optimizer='rmsprop', init='glorot_uniform'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

data = np.loadtxt("/home/abigail/nlp/MLMastery/DLwithPython/code/chapter_07/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
X = data[:, 0:8]
Y = data[:,8]

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)

optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
inits = ['glorot_uniform', 'normal', 'uniform']
epochs = [50, 100, 150]
batches = [5, 10, 20]

param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches, init=inits)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']

for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with %r" % (mean, stdev, param))



# your code
elapsed = int(time.time() - start_time)
print('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(elapsed // 3600, (elapsed % 3600 // 60), elapsed % 60))
```

Comment: Your script probably doesn't put enough computational load in the GPUs, if the model is small then the GPU won't be faster than a CPU.

Comment: Yes it is using the whole 4 GPUs. But it seems your model doesn't even need that large ram and computation.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, my desktop took 1 hour to complete the grid search, and I am hoping this 4-gpu should be much faster. However it doesn't. It is still running. Looks like it also needs to take 1 hour.

Comment: Grid search is another thing, 1 hour is reasonable.

Comment: @Sraw I pasted the full code. It simply doesn't run faster on this big machine.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, GPU doesn't help? I saw in another post it suggested :"model = make_parallel(model, 2)" with keras_extras. Would that help?

Comment: Your model is too small, GPUs are used for models with millions of parameters.

Comment: Why doesn't the GPU version faster than the CPU version on this big machine? They are both still running.

Comment: OK. I will try large models if that's the case.